# Text overflowing off the page on IE9/10 within table

Tags: html, wordpress, css, css-tables

I've got a slight issue with a website - where the content is kept within a table and displays fine on every browser besides IE 9 / 10 where the text flows off the page and out the width of the table.

I've tried a number of different fixes but seem to not be having much success.

Example page: [here](http://www.swaledalecountryholidays.co.uk/1717-2/)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

buddy You can use

word-wrap properties of css3

like

```
p
{
width:9em; 
border:1px solid #000000;
word-break:break-all;
}
```

supported in IE 9/10